# How do I tell which permissions I have on a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Is there a SQL query  I can run (or some other way) that will show the permissions I have been granted or denied? I vaguely recall something like this in MySQL or Oracle but I need something for SQL Server.

Thanks!

Update 1: The permissions I need to know about are more granular. For example, in this case, I need to see if I have been granted "View Any Definition". This issue comes up somewhat often as the DBAs have our dbs locked down. We can get the permissions we need, we just need to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802.aspx):

```
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(NULL, NULL, 'VIEW ANY DEFINITION');
```